# How to convert timestamp to date in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I like to convert my timestamp columns to date and time format. How should I write the query from presto? my timestamp is UTC time.  Thank you very much

```
Timestamp format"1506929478589"
After query convert it looks like "2016-10-25 21:04:08.436"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can convert `timestamp` to `date` with `cast(col as date)` or [`date(col)`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the date_format function (docs here: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)

Here's an example:

```
date_format(charges.created, '%Y-%m') as rev_month
```

If for some reason you're comparing dates you don't need to do the conversion like that, you can do the following

```
where customers.created BETWEEN timestamp '2018-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND timestamp '2018-05-01 00:00:00.000'
```